# How can I prevent my computer from hijacking the F10 Key?

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys, acer-aspire

I recently purchased an Acer Aspire 1080.

When I try to debug a program in Visual Studio on this laptop, and attempt to use the <kbd>F10</kbd> hotkey for the "Step Over" command, something else hijacks the hotkey and opens up a vertical control of some sort (ovaled in the screenshot here):

[image]

How can I get my <kbd>F10</kbd> back, so I don't have to manually select "Step Over" from the Debug menu each time?

Comment: I would uninstall the OEM software responsible for the overlay or change the shortcut for the Step-Over functionality

Comment: @Ramhound: How would I know what to uninstall?

Comment: Acer's response would be to hold the `FN` key while tapping `F10`, and there do seem to be bios options to disable "Action Keys", though I'm not sure if you can remap or disable just one. I'm disappointed in Acer. for as many queries as I'm seeing on their community forums, that there isn't a meaningful support document that comes up on the first page of google is not heartening.

Comment: @ClayShannon - Any software that identifies the author has Acer

Comment: There is probably also an "Fn-Lock" somewhere on your keyboard that can be disabled.  If such a thing exists, turn it off and the function keys will go back to defaults.  After that, to do the volume "thing", you will have to hit `Fn-F10`.

Answer (score 3):

Your keyboard has apparently two keys to control the audio volume level up and down.
These functions should be indicated as secondary functions on the keys,
but in your computer they are the default.

You may look for a way of reversing the default behavior of the two keys
to be function keys (F10 and the other) rather than volume control.

The article
[How to Choose Whether Your Function Keys are F1-F12 Keys or Special Keys](https://www.howtogeek.com/235351/how-to-choose-whether-your-function-keys-are-f1-f12-keys-or-special-keys/)
lists some methods that perhaps pertain to your computer:

- Toggle them using the <kbd>Fn</kbd> Lock key
- Change an Option in the BIOS or UEFI Settings.
  For example, on some Dell laptops this option is found under
  *Advanced > Function Key Behavior*.
  On Acer this
  [seems to be](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/534048/function-keys-with-or-without-fn-holding)
  in the BIOS *Main* menu, where
  "Function key behavior" needs to be changed to "Function keys":

  [image]
- Other computer manufacturers make accessible these keyboard settings
  in a configuration tool that is pre-installed or downloadable from their website.

If one of the above methods is not available for your computer,
you may still forcefully map the volume keys to their matching function keys
using the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example AutoHotkey script maps Volume Up to <kbd>F9</kbd>
and Volume Down to <kbd>F10</kbd> (these keys are just a guess on my part):

```
Volume_Up::F9
Volume_Down::F10
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

AutoHotkey documentation: [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).

Comment: Thanks; I wish I could give both of you the Bounty.

Answer (score 2):

That's volume control GUI. Your laptop's <kbd>F__</kbd> keys act as media keys by default. It's a default setting for many (most?) laptops nowadays. These keys should have secondary glyphs on them showing their alternative action. You can use <kbd>Fn</kbd> key as a modifier to use them as proper <kbd>F__</kbd> keys.

Some BIOSes have an option to change this setting permanently. Other laptops let you toggle it by pressing a key combination, for example <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (unfortunately I don't remember which manufacturer used this shortcut). I couldn't find the manual for the model you've specified, so I can't provide more detailed answer.

If it's just the single <kbd>F10</kbd> key that acts this way and the rest of the top row works as function keys (in particular neither <kbd>F9</kbd> nor <kbd>F11</kbd> also change volume), then this looks like a BIOS bug. Check if newer BIOS versions are available or wait for an update.

It's possible that this feature can be disabled by uninstalling some piece of Acer software, but again, I wasn't able to find "Acer Aspire 1080" on their website to look for anything suspicious in their driver downloads. You can try removing Acer programs related to hotkeys and/or power management - one of these may act as a bridge between keystrokes and OS.

Comment: Fn+toggle keys works, thanks! Not as handy as just hitting F10, etc., but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Programs and Settings" or "Add/Remove Programs".  In the list, find the entry for the software "Launch Manager", probably published by Acer.  Remove it and reboot.

Comment: Sounds tempting, but I'm afraid of what else might be affected by removing that.

Comment: It's just a piece of Acer bloatware.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Some of this "bloatware" enables some laptop features. For example I've seen an Acer laptop that required one of Acer programs for the WiFi toggle to work.